# Parsing a huge XML file using events

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I have a XML file which is a concatenation of multiple XML files. 
Something like

```
<xml>
    <a>
         <b> </b>
         <c> </c>
         ........
    </a>
     <a>
         <b> </b>
         <c> </c>
         ........
    </a>
     <a>
         <b> </b>
         <c> </c>
         ........
    </a>
</xml>
```

Here, all the a's are xmls themselves. The size of the XML itself varies upto 70GB!

Since I need to pick few of these XMLs randomly(and due to obvious size restrictions, I have to do this without reading whole file into memory), I thought of using `iterparse(pathRawXML, events=('start', 'end')):`. I think it works, have not tested with huge file yet.

My problem is, I cant seem to read all contents within tags such as .

Here is the code I have written,

```
     xml = ''
     xml_content = False
     filename = 'SomeFile' + str(random.randint(0, 10))

    for event, elem in etree.iterparse(pathRawXML, events=('start', 'end')):
        tname = strip_tag_name(elem.tag)

        if event == 'start':
            if tname == 'a' and xml_content == False and elem.text is not None:
                xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' '<' + tname + '>' + elem.parse
                xml_content = True
            elif tname != 'a' and xml_content == True and elem.text is not None:
                xml = xml + '<' + tname + '>' + elem.text
            elif tname == 'REC':
                xml_content = False
                with io.open(PATH_SPLIT_XML + '\\' + filename + '.xml', 'w',
                             encoding='utf-8') as output:
                    output.write(xml)
                xml = ''
            elem.clear()
```

What attribute or function of 'elem' will give me data in below format,

```
  <a>
         <b> </b>
         <c> </c>
         ........
    </a>
```

Comment: Do you really mean 'randomly'? Would you mind explaining what the overall task is - it might help somebody to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Yes, the process is random picking up of few of the xmls in the big xml file that I have. Rest of the procedure wont matter to the solution.